# Create Range with inclusive end value when stepping

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any way to create a range which *includes* the end value when using a step which doesn't align?

For instance the following yields:

```
scala> Range.inclusive(0, 35, 10)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 10, 20, 30)
```

But I would also like the end value (35) included like so:

```
scala> Range.inclusive(0, 35, 10)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 10, 20, 30, 35)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with the current definition/ implementation. It would be strange behaviour to have the step the same for all intermediate elements but different from the last.

Comment: Yes that makes sense - however I was considering a use case where a collection (table) could be effectively partitioned into chunks using column indexes. thanks.

Comment: Depending on whether you really need the indices, you could use `.grouped` (I regard explicit indices in a loop as often a code smell)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, not a standard semantics. A workaround,

```
for (i <- 0 to 35 by 10) yield if (35 % 10 != 0 && 35 - i < 10) 35 else i
```

where you must replace the boundary and step values as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround could come in handy although I'm going to revisit my approach and come up with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution does not work because it omits the value "30". Here is a unfold-style solution that produces a list rather than a sequence.

```
def unfoldRange(i: Int, j: Int, s: Int): List[Int] = {
  if (i >= j) List(j)
  else i :: unfoldRange(i+s,j,s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can tackle this by extending Range with the [Pimp my Library](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern as well.

```
object Extensions {
  implicit def RichRange(value: Range) = new {
    def withEnd: IndexedSeq[Int] = {
      if (value.last != value.end) value :+ value.end
      else value
    }
  }
}
```

although you get an IndexedSeq[Int] rather than a range. Use it like:

```
import Extensions._
0 to 5 by 2 withEnd // produces 0, 2, 4, 5
```